# Await not waiting for previous code block to be executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, discord.js, async.js

I am trying to make a discord bot using node js nd i am trying to get the username as a response nd want to send a thank you after the user enters his/her username. But both the messages , the text to ask for a username nd the thank you get sent at the same time pls help.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'create',
    description: "help page",
    async pls(bot,message,args){
       
      if(!args[2]){
          message.channel.send('Server nickname was not passed');
          return;
      }
      var details = {nickname:'',username:'',pass:'',ip:''};
      details.nickname = args[2];

      message.channel.send('Please check your private messages');
  
      await message.author.send('Enter your username (PLS enter in 30 seconds)') 
        .then((newmsg) => { 
          newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content, {
          max: 1,
          time: 15000,
          errors: ['time'],
          })
          .then((collected) => {
            details.username = collected.first().content;
            console.log(details);
        
          })
          .catch(() => {
            newmsg.channel.send('time ran out');
          });
        })
      ;

      await message.channel.send('thanks');
      
        
         
        
        
        

    }
}
```

Comment: you don't use `await` _and_ `.then()`: either try/await/catch the promise, or use .then.catch, but don't do both. Now you're awaiting the _result of then()_, which is nothing

Comment: perhaps `return newmsg.channel.awaitMessages .....`

Answer (score -1):

First thing is that you shouldn't have to use `await` and `then` in the same line. Both are a notation used for functions that return a Promise, and both tell the code to wait for that Promise to come back. Then, if you want "thanks" to appear no matter which occurs, you should use `finally` which runs only after either the try or catch block appears.

That said, it should look like this:

```
await message.author.send('Enter your username (PLS enter in 30 seconds)');
messages.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content, {
    max: 1,
    time: 15000,
    errors: ['time'],
}).then((collected) => {
    details.username = collected.first().content;
    console.log(details);
}).catch(() => {
     message.channel.send('time ran out');
}).finally(() =>{
     await message.channel.send('thanks');
});
```